# ImportError: cannot import name 'imarray' from 'impy' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/impy.py)

Tags: python

I am using Jupyter Lab for image processing and am trying to implement hough circle transform but I keep getting this error in my imports.

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-695140ab07cc> in <module>
      1 get_ipython().system('pip install impy')
----> 2 from impy import imarray
      3 import numpy as np
      4 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      5 from scipy.ndimage import imread

ImportError: cannot import name 'imarray' from 'impy' (C:\Users\himad\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\impy.py)
```

I've looked up many solutions but none of them seem to work. Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: Does `impy` have `imarray` in it? Looking here: https://github.com/hanjinliu/impy/blob/main/impy/__init__.py I find only `ImgArray` and `LazyImgArray`

Comment: Also, there is another package named `impy` on PyPI: https://pypi.org/project/impy/. Which one are you using?

Comment: For the first one, you actually need to use `pip install impy-array`, see https://pypi.org/project/impy-array/